# I keep hearing 'matrix multiplication' to refer to any number of operations

Tags: linear-algebra

I always thought the term 'matrix multiplication' referred to the operation where you multiply two matrices as in calculating an inner product, as described [on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product).

Right now, I'm taking a class taught by a computer scientist, and he has referred to a convolution (as done in image processing) as a matrix multiplication. He's also been a bit hand-wavey on some other operations, and my ears have perked up.

I'm starting to wonder if 'matrix multiplication' just refers to some class of operations. Is this the case?

Comment: Convolution is not literally matrix multiplication. However, convolution is a linear operation, and as such can be represented by matrix multiplication (at least in the discrete case). He's still being incredibly sloppy, though, at least going by the part you quoted.

Comment: I’ve only ever heard it used for operations on matrices, but those operations can be more general than the usual one; e.g., if $A$ and $B$ are $0$-$1$ matrices of suitable dimensions it’s sometimes useful to ‘multiply’ them with an operation that puts $\bigvee_{k=1}^n(a_{ik}\land b_{kj})$ in the $(i,j)$ slot of the product. Here $\lor$ replaces $+$, and $\land$ replaces $\cdot$.

Comment: Yes, computer-scientists will refer to dot-producting of arrays (contraction) as "matrix multiplication". They talk funny about lots of things, like "functions" with a trivial domain, "vectors" without a basepoint or which can’t be added (so long as the array elements are of the same type—and stored in a [particular](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm) way), and "tensors" are multi-dimensional arrays. Hey, whatever brings the [grant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGQAP0GxlW8) [money](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a/glossary.pdf) in.

Comment: At a talk given by a computer scientist to statisticians, the speaker noted that he wasn’t allowed to use the word "monad" in speaking to statisticians, but when he gave the talk to computer scientists he couldn’t speak of `sine`. Computer scientists apparently don’t believe in trigonometry. (This may be related to their definition of matrix multiplication.)